# How can I use my JVC as a webcam on my HP pavilion laptop?

Tags: video, camcorder

So I have a JVC Everio GZ-MG360BU handycam and a HP Pavilion DV2000 Laptop.

The JVC has three ports - USB, A/V and DC (for charger).
My lap has a S-Video port (Is it an input or output port?)

How can I use the JVC as my webcam?? Do I need a firewire or S-Video cable?

Thanks in advance

Kaushik

Answer (score 1):

On page 31 of the JVC Everio GZ-MG360BU manual it describes how you can hook it up to your TV using the A/V or S-Video outputs of your camera.

http://resources.jvc.com/Resources/00/01/13/57.PDF

Unfortunately the S-Video port on the HP Pavilion DV2000 is output only.

How do you hook up the A/V cable to your HP when this HP laptop does not have separate stereo line in audio or an RCA type video input as is the layout of the A/V cable?

You may want to look at an A/V to USB adapter:
http://compare.ebay.com/like/120691660283?var=lv&ltyp=AllFixedPriceItemTypes&var=sbar

I am assuming that you want to use the JVC camera over the built in webcam that comes with your HP laptop because the JVC should have better resolution and a zoom lens?

Caution: The image sent to the computer from your JVC will likely have the status information text/graphics over laid on it such as REC on/off unless the JVC has a way of clearing the display.